# Discord.py Variables

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord

I'm creating a Discordbot, that let me find out information about a IP-Address using a jsonapi. However I defined the IP within my configfile (`ip = config.get("IP"`). Now I want to do, that sues can pass the IP as a Argument after the command, then the given IP should be temporarily stored into the variable as long as the process is running and afterwards after the embed has been sent it should remove the IP from the variable. It would be nice, if anyone could help me with that.

```
import discord
import requests
import json
from discord.ext import commands

with open("config.json") as config:
    config = json.load(config)
    developer = config.get("Developer")
    token = config.get("Token")
    appid = config.get("ApplicationID")
    prefix = config.get("Prefix")
    apikey = config.get("API-KEY")
    ipadress = config.get("IP-Adress")

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, Intents=discord.Intents.all(), help_command=None)
    response = requests.get(f"https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey={apikey}&ip={ipadress}")


    def jprint(obj):
        # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
        text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        print(text)

    # jprint(response.json())
call_code = response.json()["calling_code"]
city = response.json()["city"]
connection_type = response.json()["connection_type"]
continent_code = response.json()["continent_code"]
continent_name = response.json()["continent_name"]
country_capital = response.json()["country_capital"]
country_code2 = response.json()["country_code2"]
country_code3 = response.json()["country_code3"]
country_name = response.json()["country_name"]
country_tld = response.json()["country_tld"]
currency = response.json()["currency"]
currency_code = response.json()["currency"]["code"]
currency_name = response.json()["currency"]["name"]
currency_symbol = response.json()["currency"]["symbol"]
district = response.json()["district"]
geoname_id = response.json()["geoname_id"]
ip = response.json()["ip"]
is_eu = response.json()["is_eu"]
isp = response.json()["isp"]
languages = response.json()["languages"]
latitude = response.json()["latitude"]
longitude = response.json()["longitude"]
organization = response.json()["organization"]
state_prov = response.json()["state_prov"]
time_zone = response.json()["time_zone"]
time_zone_name = response.json()["time_zone"]["name"]
time_zone_offset = response.json()["time_zone"]["offset"]
time_zone_current_time = response.json()["time_zone"]["current_time"]
time_zone_current_time_unix = response.json()["time_zone"]["current_time_unix"]
time_zone_is_dst = response.json()["time_zone"]["is_dst"]
time_zone_dst_savings = response.json()["time_zone"]["dst_savings"]
zipcode = response.json()["zipcode"]


@bot.command(name="location")
async def geolookup(ctx, args: ip):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Location Lookup:",
        description="Outputs a lot of Infos about  a IP",
        color=0xFF0C93)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Calling-Code: ",
        value=f"{call_code}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="City: ",
        value=f"{city}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Continent-Code: ",
        value=f"{continent_code}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Continent-Name: ",
        value=f"{continent_name}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Country-Capital: ",
        value=f"{country_capital}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Country-Code2: ",
        value=f"{country_code2}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Country-Code3: ",
        value=f"{country_code3}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Country-Name: ",
        value=f"{country_name}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Country-TLD: ",
        value=f"{country_tld}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Currency: ",
        value=f"Code: {currency_code} \n"
              f"Name: {currency_name} \n"
              f"Symbol: {currency_symbol}", inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="District: ",
        value=f"{district}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Geoname-ID: ",
        value=f"{geoname_id}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="IP: ",
        value=f"{args}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="IS-EU: ",
        value=f"{is_eu}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="ISP: ",
        value=f"{isp}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Languages: ",
        value=f"{languages}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Latitude: ",
        value=f"{latitude}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Longitude: ",
        value=f"{longitude}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Organization: ",
        value=f"{organization}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="State-Prov: ",
        value=f"{state_prov}",
        inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Time-Zone: ",
        value=f"Name: {time_zone_name} \n"
              f"Offset: {time_zone_offset} \n"
              f"Current Time: {time_zone_current_time} \n"
              f"Current Time Unix: {time_zone_current_time_unix} \n"
              f"is_dst: {time_zone_is_dst}\n"
              f"dst_savings: {time_zone_dst_savings}", inline=True)

    embed.add_field(
        name="Zipcode: ",
        value=f"{zipcode}",
        inline=True)

    embed.set_footer(text=f"Created by {developer}")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")


bot.run(token, reconnect=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`discord.ext.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) extension that you are using can easily add commands with arguments.

Reference for parameters in commands : [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters)

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command(name="greet")
async def test(ctx, arg1):
    # Do something with arg1
    embed = Embed(
            title=f"Hello {arg1}",
            color=0x00A61D,
        )

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Put the request code into a function, and call the function from the discord command.

```py
def get_ip_details(ip_address):
    response = requests.get(
        f"https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo",
        params={"apiKey":"apikey", "ip":"ip_address"}
    )
    # Check if response
    response.check_for_status()
    ip_data = {
        "call_code": response["calling_code"],
        "city": response["city"],
        "connection_type": response["connection_type"],
        "continent_code": response["continent_code"],
        "continent_name": response["continent_name"],
        "country_capital": response["country_capital"],
        "country_code2": response["country_code2"],
        "country_code3": response["country_code3"],
        "country_name": response["country_name"],
        "country_tld": response["country_tld"],
        "currency": response["currency"],
        "currency_code": response["currency"]["code"],
        "currency_name": response["currency"]["name"],
        "currency_symbol": response["currency"]["symbol"],
        "district": response["district"],
        "geoname_id": response["geoname_id"],
        "ip": response["ip"],
        "is_eu": response["is_eu"],
        "isp": response["isp"],
        "languages": response["languages"],
        "latitude": response["latitude"],
        "longitude": response["longitude"],
        "organization": response["organization"],
        "state_prov": response["state_prov"],
        "time_zone": response["time_zone"],
        "time_zone_name": response["time_zone"]["name"],
        "time_zone_offset": response["time_zone"]["offset"],
        "time_zone_current_time": response["time_zone"]["current_time"],
        "time_zone_current_time_unix": response["time_zone"]["current_time_unix"],
        "time_zone_is_dst": response["time_zone"]["is_dst"],
        "time_zone_dst_savings": response["time_zone"]["dst_savings"],
        "zipcode": response["zipcode"],
    }
```

---

Now you can call the ip_address function from your command function

```py
@bot.command(name="location")
async def get_ip_location(ctx, ip_address):
    try:
        ip_details = get_ip_details(ip_address)

        <ip_details is a dict with all the data>
        <add details to embed here>

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    except Exception:
        await ctx.send("Error fetching details")
```

---

You can also specify `int` or `bool` or any other callable function as the type of the argument, and it will try to convert the argument into that type.

You can get more details with the [Converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) section of the docs

---

**Other advice**

1. You can use the `pprint` module to pretty print stuff. You won't need the jprint function.
2. You can save `response.json()` into a variable and then get all those values out of it. You don't need to call `response.json()` everytime.
3. Use `aiohttp` instead of `requests` so that you can make requests asynchronously.
4. You can directly pass the strings into the embed, instead of using f-strings for just the string.

Comment: Thanks for the great Information. I now have a questions left i listed below:

- Whats the Syntax of aiohttp if i use it instead of requests?
-How i use pprint instead of the jprint function?

Information:
I completly rewrote my code so its now using Cogs.

Comment: I now used the code and well i get 33 Warnings with all the same Text:

Class 'Response' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances

Comment: @PepeisSad can you edit your question with your updated code? 
With the `getitem` error, you're most likely calling `response['somekey']` on the response itself, instead of updating `response = response.json()`